# How to use DSolve with vectors without decomposing into vector components?

Tags: differential-equations, vector

Given a basic, two-dimensional ballistic trajectory problem, I can solve the equations of motion using [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) (or [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)) by decomposing the vector equations of motion into equations with the scalar components, as follows:

```
DSolve[
  Flatten@{
    Thread[{rx''[t], ry''[t]} == {rx[t], -9.8 ry[t]}],
    Thread[{vx[t], vy[t]} == {rx'[t], ry'[t]}],
    {Thread[{rx[0], ry[0]} == {0, 0}],
     Thread[{vx[0], vy[0]} == {40 Cos[30 °], 
        40 Sin[30 °]}]}
    },
  {rx[t], ry[t], vx[t], vy[t]},
  t
  ];
```

But which *general* approaches are possible to do this just with "vectors"? (I'm not interested in having anyone solve this particular example per se.)

For example, something like this would be desirable:

```
DSolve[
 {
  Thread[m r''[t] == {0, -9.8} r[t]],
  Thread[v[t] == r'[t]],
  {Thread[r[0] == {0, 0}],
   Thread[v[0] == {40 Cos[30 °], 40 Sin[30 °]}]}
  },
 {r[t], v[t]},
 t
 ]
```

Surely this must be possible in some way? I understand that "vectors" are just [`Lists`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html), and that Mathematica doesn't know that I want `r[t]`, `r'[t]` or `v[t]` to be "vectors". However, using `{r[t][[1]],r[t][[2]]}` hasn't worked for me yet, either. I would also prefer to implement the method myself "manually" rather than rely on packages which I would have to see as a black box.

Comment: I've never figured out how to do this with `DSolve`.  One can write a function to replace vector functions with component/coordinate functions and then reassemble the component solutions into a vector solution. I don't know what's the matter with such an approach.  You'd think users would have asked for it and WRI considered it.

Answer (score 3):

The idea (as in my comment) is to replace a vector-valued dependent variable by coordinate functions `K[i]` for `i = 1, 2, ...`; then call `DSolve`; and finally reassemble the solution coordinates into a vector-valued solutions.

```
ClearAll[reassembleSols, vectorize];
reassembleSols[sols_, fns_, var_, dim_] := Function[sol0, MapThread[
     Function[{f, s},
      If[FreeQ[f, var],
       f -> Function @@ {var, s},
       f -> s]],
     {fns, Partition[sol0, dim]}]
    ] /@ (Table[K[i][var], {i, 1 + Length[fns]*dim}] /. sols);

SetAttributes[vectorize, HoldAll];
vectorize[dim_, DSolve[ode_, f_, var_, rest___]] :=
 With[{fns = Flatten[{f}]},
  Block @@ 
   With[{depvars = Internal`ProcessEquations`FindDependentVariables[ode, var]},
    Hold[
     depvars,
     Module[{rules, sols},
      Do[(#[\[FormalT]_] = Table[K[i][\[FormalT]], {i, 1 + j*dim - dim, j*dim}]) &@
        depvars[[j]], {j, Length[depvars]}];
      rules = 
       Table[depvars[[j]] -> Table[K[i], {i, 1 + j*dim - dim, j*dim}],
        {j, Length[depvars]}];
      sols = DSolve[ode, Flatten[fns /. rules], var, rest];
      Clear @@ depvars;
      If[FreeQ[sols, DSolve],
       reassembleSols[sols, fns, var, dim],
       sols]
     ]]]
```

OP's example.

```
vectorize[2,
 DSolve[{m r''[t] == {{0, 0}, {0, -10}}. r[t], 
   v[t] == r'[t], {r[0] == {0, 0}, 
    v[0] == {40 Cos[30 °], 40 Sin[30 °]}}}, {r[t], 
   v[t]}, t]
 ]
(*
  {{r[t] -> {20 Sqrt[3] t,
      -I Sqrt[10] *
        E^(-((I Sqrt[10] t)/Sqrt[m])) (-1 + E^((2 I Sqrt[10] t)/Sqrt[m])) Sqrt[m]}, 
    v[t] -> {20 Sqrt[3], 
      10 E^(-((I Sqrt[10] t)/Sqrt[m])) (1 + E^((2 I Sqrt[10] t)/Sqrt[m]))}}}
*)
```

Note: The variables (`{r, v}` in the OP's example) are defined to be functions of the form

```
r[t_] = {K[1][t], K[2][t]}
```

inside the `Block`.  These definitions cause the `ode` to evaluate to a componentwise system of equations when `DSolve` is called.  When defined as functions this way, the derivatives of `r` are automatically computed properly in the system passed to `DSolve`.  If we were to apply `rules`, this would not happen.  Afterwards, these definitions are cleared in order to reassemble the solutions for `r[t]` etc. so that `r[t]` stays `r[t]` and does not evaluate to a vector of `K`'s.

Comment: I should have pointed out that in the OP's ODE, there was `{0, -9.8} r[t]`, which I changed to a `Dot` product.  The problem is that `Times` threads prematurely, before `r[t]` is replaced by the coordinates.  `Dot`, however, won't evaluate until `r[t]` becomes a vector, which is the desired behavior.