# Working with vector-valued functions to solve an ODE

Tags: differential-equations, vector

Let's say I have a simple vector-valued ODE given by 
$y'(t) = K*y(t)$

where K is a matrix $K_{n_{X}n}$. Let's assume that the matrix is $K_{21_{X}21}$, 
$K = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
k_{1_{X}1} & k_{1_{X}2} & \cdots & k_{1_{X}21} \\
k_{2_{X}1} & k_{2_{X}2} & \cdots & k_{2_{X}21} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
k_{21_{X}1} & k_{21_{X}2} & \cdots & k_{21_{X}21} \end{array} \right] $ 
As long as I know (and I don't know much because I've been working with Mathematica for just a couple weeks), I should provide the initial conditions with the same lenght that the matrix K, so $y[0]=\left\{y_{1},...,y_{21}\right\}$, right? So my question is, can I relate a specifc number $k_{n,m}$ of the matrix to a specific number $y_{i}$ of the initial conditions to solve the ODE? So, for example:  
$y'[0]=k_{1_{X}1}*y_{1}$;  $ y'[0]=k_{1_{X}2}*y_{1}$; $... y'[0]=k_{1_{X}21}*y_{1}$; 
 
$y'[1]=k_{2_{X}1}*y_{2}$; $y'[1]=k_{2_{X}2}*y_{2}$; $... y'[1]=k_{2_{X}21}*y_{2}$; 
.
.
.
$y'[20]=k_{20_{X}1}*y_{20}$;$y'[20]=k_{20_{X}2}*y_{20}$; $y'[20]=k_{20_{X}20}*y_{20}$

Is that possible to build and solve an ODE like that or is that exactly what MA does? Basically I want to solve the differential equation for each value of $k$.
I'm used to program using fortran so I'm still building the code on MA thinking on my background on fortran language, where I'd solve it in a 'do' loop. I hope I made myself clear enough to anyone help me with that.
Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77922/ (`DSolve`), http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14407/ (`NDSolve`) ... many others related questions for `NDSolve`, too

Comment: I'm a little confused by your notation here.  When you say $y'[0] = k_1x1 * y_1$, the left-hand side of the equation looks like a vector of 21 components, while the right-hand side looks like a scalar.  But you can't set those equal to each other, so obviously I'm missing something.